# When to use "have you got/gotten it"?

Tags: present-perfect

As soon as I finish explaining a math question, I ask my students,

> Do you get it?

Here, I don't think it's right to ask "have you got/gotten it".

When should I use "have you got/gotten it"?

How about this scenario?

Thirty minutes later, when I conclude the class, I ask them again to check if they've understood it,

> Peter, have you got it ? (BE)...Susan, how about you?

> Peter, have you gotten it? (AE)...Susan, how about you?

Answer (score 1):

Often, the present perfect is used to signal the past, **but not when**:

- Person 1: "Right, so, **have you got** (gotten it) it?. [meaning: to buy something]
- Person 2: Yes, I have.
- Person 1: Really? Just **when did you get it**?
- Person 2: About **two hours ago**. At the supermarket. [notice the shift in tense].

In the example above, the emphasis is, at first, on the action of getting (buying) something. Not when it was purchased specifically.

Get as understand

- Person 1: Right, so, did you get it? [meaning: to understand something]
- Person 2: No, not really. Can you explain it again?

That said, in terms of explaining something to someone, we would usually use the simple past here. Why? Because if you are asking someone about understanding some explanation or thing, you are interested in a thing as finished or over. "Did you get it?" is the same thing as "Did you understand it?" Of course, you could say: "Have you understood it?" but it is **less likely coming right after you have *explained* it**.

Comment: When do you use *Did you get it*? Right after you explain it or some unspecified time (say, ten minutes) after you explain it?

Comment: Would you use *do you get it* when you finish explaining it?

Comment: Did you get it? [when I **explained it**]. Do you get it? [now or in general.]